# Convert to Number from a String but only strings that are valid integers

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I have an input which is always a *String*. The string can contain an integer or text:

```
intputString = "1";
```

or

```
inputString = "hey";
```

I would like to convert to a *Number* only those inputs that contain integers. Otherwise, the inputs need to remain the same.

For example, if I have an integer:

```
inputString = "288";          // <-- Make the conversion 
desiredOutput = 288;
```

And if I have non-integer text:

```
inputString = "hey";         // <-- Don't make the conversion and leave it as is
desiredOutput = "hey";
```

I was using `Numbers(inputString)` but this converts text values into `NaN`.

How can I achieve this conversion?

**EDIT:** None of the answers from the duplicate question answers this question.

Comment: you can check isNaN() before converting

Comment: @Strikegently None of the answers of that post is valid for this one.

Comment: @MateuszJuruś what do you mean? `typeof("22") ` is still `string` and `typeof(NaN)` is still `number`

Comment: How about those inputs: `-3`, `2.5`, `1e1` and `430583409583409583049`? Do you want them to be converted?

Comment: @georg - The OP is correct that the supplied duplicate is not valid. Avión already knows how to convert a string into an integer. What is required is to keep the non-integer strings in their original state instead of being converted to `NaN`. (To be fair `isNaN` does appear once, but it is buried deeply in a long answer, and more as a footnote suggesting that it might be necessary, rather than in a supplied bit of code.) A *much* better dupe target would be [How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319).

Comment: @robinCTS: "convert a string to a number" is a topic most JS developers get wrong, mostly because there are quick and obvious (but inaccurate) ways to do that in the language. The referred thread has at least a few reasonable answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050154/989121, the OP is welcome to study them and revisit their accepted solution later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply cast the input to `Number`. If the result is `NaN`,  return the original string, else return the casted value.

```js
function convert(input) {
    if(input === "0") {
        return 0;
    }
    return Number(input) || input;
}

console.log(convert("288"));
console.log(convert("hey"));
console.log(convert("0"));
console.log(convert(""));
```

Comment: This will fail for "0"

Comment: Yep was editing when you commented

Comment: this will return floats though if input is float

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
if(!isNaN(inputString))
    output = inputString;
else
    //Input is not a number
```